# Firebase Firestore read nested object values in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read nested values from Cloud Firestore in my Android project, but I was not able to find any documentation on how to do this.

### Example document:

[image: Firestore example]

### This is what I tried:

```
Object myMap = documentSnapshot.get("my-map");
Timestamp myTimestamp = ((DocumentSnapshot) myMap).getTimestamp("my-timestamp");
Date myDate = myTimestamp.toDate();
```

This does not work because `myMap` cannot be casted to a `DocumentSnapshot`.

### So my question is:

How do I read the `my-timestamp` field as a `Date` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out while writing the question and the answer is quite simple.

The return value of `documentSnapshot.get("my-map")` can be cast to a `Map`, which can be used to read the nested properties.

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, Object>) documentSnapshot.get("my-map");
Date myDate = (Date) myMap.get("my-timestamp");
```

Answer (score 0):

An ever simpler way would to get the date would be to use DocumentSnapshot's [getDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getDate(java.lang.String)) method:

> Returns the value of the field as a Date.

In code should look like this:

```
Date myTimestamp = documentSnapshot.getDate("my-timestamp");
```